# Filter duplicate rows from result excluding one column?

Tags: mysql, sql, duplicates

I have a table like this -

```
uid  test1  test2  test3  test4  test5
10    x1     x2     x3     x4     x5
11    x6     x7     x8     x9     x10
12    x11    x12    x13    x14    x15
13    x16    x17    x18    x19    x20
14    x16    x17    x18    x19    x20
15    x21    x22    x23    x24    x25
16    x26    x27    x28    x29    x30
```

As seen from the above table rows with uid 13 and 14 have same values for all the columns except uid.

So i want to filter all rows with exact same values excluding column uid (ie column uid can defer in values), In the final result i want row for duplicate or similar rows and in 
it's uid column all of the duplicates ones uid in comma seperated format.

Expected results -

```
uid    test1  test2  test3  test4  test5
10      x1     x2     x3     x4     x5
11      x6     x7     x8     x9     x10
12      x11    x12    x13    x14    x15
13,14   x16    x17    x18    x19    x20
15      x21    x22    x23    x24    x25
16      x26    x27    x28    x29    x30
```

I tried using [DISTINCTROW](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html), but it requires all columns to be same in order to consider row to be duplicate.

Any suggestions appreciated.

**EDIT:** I am using MYSQL as a database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use grouping by columns you want to be distinct in the output, applying [`GROUP_CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) on the column or columns you want to display as a list or lists.

```
SELECT
  GROUP_CONCAT(uid),
  test1, test2, test3, test4, test5
FROM atable
GROUP BY test1, test2, test3, test4, test5
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use group by CONCAT ( THE COLUMS TO TEST FOR DUPLICATE VALUES ).

Or try using the query given here :
http://oscarvalles.wordpress.com/2008/01/28/sql-distinct-on-one-column-only/

Then use GROUP_CONCAT  to merge the columns which are duplicates with particular columns
(all except first on your case ).